# How can I implement a custom display widget for an existing field?

Tags: 7, entities

Basically I want to have my own widget as a choice in the widget drop down of an existing field type; and/or I want to be able to call [field_view_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7) on a field and have it display the way I need, using info from the field itself and elsewhere.

I can probabaly do what I need with [template_preprocess_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) but I would prefer to hook the existing admin interface for selecting the output of the form.

I'm assuming that a solution is available that would allow the output of the field to be the way I configure it any place the field can be displayed, Views, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Examples project](http://drupal.org/project/examples) on drupal.org has a field example, showing how to implement a widget.

Basically you need to implement [`hook_field_widget_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_info/7), and for 'field types' include the field type your widget is for.